# In Python Selenium, how to wait for either two elements to be found and continue with the loop

Tags: python, selenium

In order to get the text I want

`d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/table[1]/tbody/tr'))).text`

I need to wait for either `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.related-keyword-item')))` or `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.related-keyword-item')))` to be uploaded with certain text value to get `d1`.

Above `ky`  is the code for entering the page, my problem is the code below `ky`.

If `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.related-keyword-item')))` is  not  found, it will wait for `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.related-keyword-item')))`. But I don't want to wait for 60 seconds to continue to wait for second element if there is already no first element.

And if I add more than thousands of keywords in `ky`, this will appear `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: try`

I have tried to fix this problem more than a week and I'm desperate for someone to help me out. 
This is my code and the code works well only with hundreds of keywords in `ky`.

```
import xlrd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Kim woo jae\PycharmProjects\100개 키워드\chromedriver.exe")
list = []
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

driver.get("https://itemscout.io/keyword/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
b = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/input')))
b.clear()
b.send_keys('화장대')
c = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/span')))
c.click()
d = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[ @id="container"]/table[1]/tbody/tr'))).text



ky = '화장대','침대전신거울','서랍장','까사마루3단행거','옷장', '5단서랍장','6평농막'

for k in ky:
    b1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/input')))
    b1.clear()
    b1.send_keys(k)
    c1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/span')))
    c1.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.related-keyword-item')))
    except:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.related-keyword-item')))
    d1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/table[1]/tbody/tr'))).text
    d1 = (d1).replace(',', '.')
    d1 = ' '.join(d1.splitlines())
    d1 = d1.replace(' ', ',')
    result = [x.strip() for x in d1.split(',')]

    d = [result[2]]
    s = [result[3]]
    c = [result[4]]
    print([k],d,s,c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use or `,` in the `CSS_SELECTOR`. It will return the first if found, else the second. It will check for both every the DOM is pulled

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.related-keyword-item, span.related-keyword-item')))
```